# Deploy FSLab XPlot Graphics to Web

Tags: wordpress, azure, f#, fslab

I'm interested in deploying interactive graphics built with FSLabs XPlot wrappers around plot.ly and google charts to wordpress, xamarin and good old web platforms.  I have scoured the documentation, which does a fantastic job of demoing the charting capabilities, but not so much how to integrate into a wordpress site, a xamarin app or an angular application with an F# Web Api back end.

Docs on this or pointesr would be be beyond helpful!

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As nobody has found an answer and I have found the answer since posting, I have decided to post it here as a legit answer which solved my problem.

**Step 1:**

Create a class library for your charts in the foreign F# language, because most web dev’s use C#

[image]
**Step 2:**

Create a sweet chart:

[image]
**Step 3:**

Reference and Serve sweet chart from C#:

1. Note you put all of the policy control into the hands of the web dev with no additional components.
2. Want google/twitter auth?  Get it!  Want routing controls, you have it all right here, no additional stuff, no additional staffing needed.
3. No additional admins needed.

[image]
**Step 4:**

Bind Chart to web application…

[image]
Note that you need to make a call to drawChart(); to ensure the chart draws, otherwise you have a race condition.  That line of code is not pictured, but important.

**Step 5:**

Enjoy your charts

[image]